# CSS Button rendering different in Webkit

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a button inside a div with a variable width, and I am facing a problem where the button is being rendered differently only in Safari.

In all browsers it renders like this:

[image: All Web Browsers]
But in Safari (and all Webkit based browsers), it renders like this:

[image]

Heres whre the component is called:

```
...<some react code>...
  return isDownMd ? (
    <Container isShowingTour={isShowingTour} style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
      <PerformanceDiv
        isShowingTour={isShowingTour}
        data-testid="price-indicator"
        className="indicators container"
        ref={mobileRef}
      >
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('weeklySales')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('completedOrders')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('salesTotal')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('cancelledOrders')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('averageTicket')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('productsVisit')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
        <SingleIndicatorDiv>{renderIndicator('conversionRate')}</SingleIndicatorDiv>
      </PerformanceDiv>
      {showArrows[0] && (showAllArrows || !isDownXs) ? (
        <ArrowLeft
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleClickArrow(true)}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          data-testid="arrow-left-md"
        >
          <ArrowForwardIos style={{ width: '75%' }} />
        </ArrowLeft>
      ) : null}
      {showArrows[1] && (showAllArrows || !isDownXs) ? (
        <ArrowRight
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleClickArrow(false)}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          data-testid="arrow-right-md"
        >
          <ArrowForwardIos style={{ width: '75%' }} />
        </ArrowRight>
      ) : null}
    </Container>
  ) : (
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
      <GridPerformance
        container
        item
        spacing={2}
        data-testid="price-indicator"
        className="indicators"
        ref={gridRef}
      >
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '208px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('weeklySales')}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '220px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('completedOrders')}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '220px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('salesTotal')}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '220px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('cancelledOrders')}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '220px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('averageTicket')}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '220px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('productsVisit')}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ minWidth: '220px' }}>
          {renderIndicator('conversionRate')}
        </Grid>
      </GridPerformance>
      {showArrows[0] ? (
        <ArrowLeft
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleClickArrow(true)}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          data-testid="arrow-left"
        >
          <ArrowForwardIos style={{ width: '75%' }} />
        </ArrowLeft>
      ) : null}
      {showArrows[1] ? (
        <ArrowRight
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleClickArrow(false)}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          data-testid="arrow-right"
        >
          <ArrowForwardIos style={{ width: '75%' }} />
        </ArrowRight>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the component's style (styled-components):

```
export const ArrowRight = styled(Button)`
  background-color: #0086ff !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 43%;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  padding: 2px !important;
  min-width: 24px;
  ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints?.down('md')} {
    right: 1%;
  }
  ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints?.down('xs')} {
    right: 3%;
  }
```

Can someone help me? I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: When ever asking such questions you should create a [mcve] that includes the final html and css results in that problem.

Comment: A side note: using `!important` is in almost any case wrong. There are only really rare cases where you really need that.

Comment: @t.niese I updated the question with additional code

Comment: A [mcve] would be the resulting css and html not the code that generates it, with what you show here we don't know how the final css and html looks like . Only only those parts that are relevant for reproducing it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if you have a positioned ancestor element?

i.e.

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute_positioning

Comment: Yes, the parent component already has the position: asbolute defined. Please check the additional code i added to the question.

Comment: It's greaat that you are trying to help, but this is not an answer to the question, and should not have been posted as an answer. Requests for clarification should be posted as comments to the question. If you lack the privilege to post comments then you should first work on gathering reputation points.